# Fade repeating after replacing image while scrolling with javascript

Tags: javascript, scroll, transition

I'm trying to replace the logo image in heading of the page when scrolling, with fade effect. It starts working in the correct way, and the image replacement is done but while you continue scrolling down the site, the new logo continues fading.

Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function(){
    var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
      if (scroll > 100) {
          $(".navbar-fixed-top").addClass("nav-scrolled");
          $('#logo').fadeOut('',function(){
                $(this).attr('src','Template/images/logo-scrolled.png').fadeIn();
            });
      }

      else{
          $(".navbar-fixed-top").removeClass("nav-scrolled");
          $('#logo').fadeOut('',function(){
                $(this).attr('src','Template/images/logo.png');
        });
      }
  })
})
```

You can see it in [www.ultramarinosvillena.com](http://www.ultramarinosvillena.com)
How could I fix it?

Comment: You could put checks in to see if the logo is currently [visible](https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/) and [animating](https://api.jquery.com/animated-selector/) before trying to fade in or out

Comment: I'm not sure of what you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: sorry, my mistake - first thinking then posting. ;) One of the conditional statements was triggered with each scroll event - now it will only be triggered once, when the scrolling point is reached.

You should check the nav-scrolled class:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var $navbar = $(".navbar-fixed-top"),
        $logo = $("#logo"),
        currentScroll;

    $(window).on('scroll', function(){

        currentScroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        if ( currentScroll > 100 && !($navbar.hasClass('nav-scrolled')) ) {

            $navbar.addClass("nav-scrolled");
            $logo.fadeOut('',function(){
                $(this).attr('src','Template/images/logo-scrolled.png').fadeIn();
            });

        } else if ( currentScroll < 100 && $navbar.hasClass('nav-scrolled')) {

            $navbar.removeClass("nav-scrolled");
            $logo.fadeOut('',function(){
                $(this).attr('src','Template/images/logo.png').fadeIn();
            });
        }

    });
});
```

Comment: I've updated the code. It works almost perfect. Now the fading ended but when scrolling up from the bottom of the page, the initial image is not showed.

Comment: yes - the image isn't faded in again by scolling up: just change: 
`$(this).attr('src','Template/images/logo.png');` to 
 `$(this).attr('src','Template/images/logo.png').fadeIn();`